# Como exportar documentação de pacote com css usando godoc?

Tags: golang

Após escrever meu `package` sei que é possivel gerar uma pagina html com toda a documentação fornecida através de comentários no meu código;

```
godoc -html github.com/user/package > index.html
```

Porém o arquivo gerado (`index.html`) não possui nenhum css, existe uma maneira de usar o mesmo estilo que é usado se utilizarmos o `godoc` com a flag `-http`?

```
dogoc -http=:6060
```